# How to search and store specific part of text in txt files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a script in which I am able to search for a specific piece of text in a txt file and then write it to another txt file. I use two filenames. The file "in.txt" contains different parts of text that have beginning and end markers. The starting marker is a variable: for example "^ 1", "^ 2", or "^ 3". The end marker is always the same caractre "^"). 
My intention is making a code that makes it possible to search in "in.txt" for the specified variable  (for instance: "^ 3") which functions as a start marker and read from that point all the lines that folllows till I reach the end marker (which I defined as "^").
Thereafter I want to write the lines to the file "out.txt"
I'm new to pyhton and I have to learn a lot. 
Till now I googled but didn't find a solution thant I use. I found only very complicated solutions, but none of them gave me a suggestion to solve my problem (search with begin and end markers).

My code to this point is:

```
with open (f1, encoding = "utf8", errors = "ignore") as f:
    lines = f.readlines ()
    lines = [l for l in lines if "^ 3" in l]
    with open (f2, "w") as f1:
        f1.writelines (lines)
```

I only get "^ 3" in the file "out.txt". Nothing more. Not the following lines either. And I haven't figured out how to code the 'end marker' in the search line.
Please help me out! I am gratefull for every tip from more expierenced users that can help me get further with my coding abbilities. Thank you!

Comment: Can you show a sample input, maybe 3 lines

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your doing wrong but this worked fine for me. It could be you reusing your variables `lines`, `f1`

```
 with open('in.txt', 'r') as f:
     lines = f.readlines()   
     lin = [i for i in lines if '^ 3' in i]              
     with open('out.txt', 'w') as f1:
         f1.write(str(lin))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the format of my "in.txt" file.

^ 0
This is text part 0. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec purus nunc, auctor eu dignissim sed, lacinia eu urna. In laoreet, nisl sed interdum tempus, odio 
^
^ 1
This is text part 1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec purus nunc, auctor eu dignissim sed, lacinia eu urna. In laoreet, nisl sed interdum tempus, odio ^
^ 2
This is text part 2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec purus nunc, auctor eu dignissim sed, lacinia eu urna. In laoreet, nisl sed interdum tempus, odio ^
^ 3
This is text part 3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec purus nunc, auctor eu dignissim sed, lacinia eu urna. In laoreet, nisl sed interdum tempus, odio 
^
...................
...................
...................
^ 33
This is text part 33. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec purus nunc, auctor eu dignissim sed, lacinia eu urna. In laoreet, nisl sed interdum tempus, odio 
^
When I run the code I get in "out.txt"

['* 3\n', '* 33\n']

That's all. So this is not the way to get the result I want. When I want the text after the begin variable: "^ 3" Ik want to get the text:

This is text part 3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec purus nunc, auctor eu dignissim sed, lacinia eu urna. In laoreet, nisl sed interdum tempus, odio

Do you know the solution to this problem?